# Conditional Formatting using multiple vlookups

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have an excel spreadsheet and I am trying to do conditional formatting based on multiple conditions. I have to highlight the rows where (Column A value matches column C) AND (Column B matches column D). I tried 3 ways but none of them are giving me expected results-
Method 1 - I tried conditional formatting with these 2 Rules-
(VLOOKUP($A2,C2:C93,1,FALSE))>0
(VLOOKUP($B2,D2:D93,1,FALSE))>0
and applied it to $A$2:$D$5745
but this is not working as expected.

Method 2- I tried using if but this is also not providing me desired results
=if(VLOOKUP(A2,$C2:$C93,1,FALSE)>0 & VLOOKUP(B2,$D2:$D93,1,FALSE),True,False)>0
applied it to $A$2:$D$5745

Method 3- =AND((VLOOKUP($A2,C2:C93,1,FALSE))>0,(VLOOKUP($B2,D2:D93,1,FALSE))>0)
applied it to $A$2:$D$5745

To rephrase this problem- I would like to highlight all rows where CustEID in Col A and Account EID in cloumn B match CustEID in col C and Account EID in col D.

Can someone please guide me?

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Don't use `&`. Use the `AND` function to combine both of your `VLOOKUP` statements. It looks like it would be `=if(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,$C2:$C93,1,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(B2,$D2:$D93,1,FALSE)),True,False)>0`

Comment: Thanks..There was a typo- =if(AND(VLOOKUP(A2,$C2:$C93,1,FALSE)>0,VLOOKUP(B2,$D2:$D93,1,FALSE)>0),True,False)>0

Comment: Unfortunately, this too is not working as expected. Seems like it is only highlighting when (Value in cell A = Value in C )And (Value in B = Value in D). It is not doing a vertical lookup.

Comment: So you want to highlight row 2 if the value in cell A2 occurs anywhere in column C and the value of B2 occurs anywhere in column D?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what I am trying to do. A2 occurs anywhere in column C and the value of B2 occurs anywhere in column D. But as shown in the print screen above in question- the catch here is some of the values in column B are Null. I am trying to find A2 (CustEID) anywhere in column C and then do a lookup for B2 (AccountEID) anywhere in  column D. Account EIDs maybe NULL.

Comment: Also, as you can see these are not unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I was able to get working.

1. The `VLOOKUP` evaluates to return either the "found" value or `#N/A`. By modifying your formula with a logical check `>0`, this converts the result to a boolean value (`TRUE`) but **only** in the case where `VLOOKUP` is returning a valid value. In many of your cases, your formula still evaluates to `#N/A`.

So this:  `=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$93,1,FALSE)>0` will return either `TRUE` or `#N/A`.

I've modified the formula to `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$93,1,FALSE)>0,FALSE)`, which forces the entire formula to return a true boolean value `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

2. The cell range references in your formulas need to be locked into specific ranges that will not be evaluated as "relative" in the context of the conditional format formula. So your formula `VLOOKUP($A2,C2:C93,1,FALSE)` using the range `C2:C93` will also "slide" (my own terminology for this formula going "relative") as it progresses down the rows. So each of your formulas needs to lock this down with `VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$C$93,1,FALSE)`.

Notice that the only portion of the formula that stays relative is the row number -- the `2` in this case. So you'll start your conditional format setup on row 2.

3. Combining these formulas for the full test you want to apply gets you

`=AND(IFNA(VLOOKUP($A2,$C$2:$C$93,1,FALSE)>0,FALSE),IFNA(VLOOKUP($B2,$D$2:$D$93,1,FALSE)>0,FALSE))`

4. Applying this to your conditional format as a **full row** requires one last adjustment. Instead of applying your rule to the range `$A$2:$D$5745`, you have to remove the column references. So the application range becomes `$2:$5745`.

This is what I get when it's all put together:

[image]